# Domain management setting not present in aws amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, custom-domain

I have my react app, deployed and hosted at AWS amplify. No backend. While it works fine with amplify provided default URL but when I registered a custom domain using route 53 and looked for domain management setting in amplify console (like million tutorials on web said) to my surprise, there is no domain management setting coming up at all.
Could anyone help me out here. My custom domain is fully registered at route 53.

Answer (score 0):

The domains are associated with git branches.
Open your project in AWS Amplify console and open the `Hosting environments` tab (next to 'Backend environments'). You might be able to get away with "Deploy without Git provider", but if you can, setup one of the Git providers.

After that, the 'Domain management' option should appear in the `App settings' menu.